# Azure DevOps user access filtering

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-devops

We have a requirement in my project where we need to find out the repository access for users in Azure DevOps using cli.

We were able to find out the top-level access for all the users, using this CLI command as provided in the official azure-cli documents.

**Command-1**

```
az devops user list --org {Organisation-Name} --query members[].[username,emailid,accesslevel] -o table
```

The above command returns the following output:

```
Username     EmailId             AccessLevel
------------------------------------------
John Doe     john.doe@abc.com    Basic
Rick Stein   rick.stein@abc.com  Stakeholder
....
```

Next using the user's email-id extracted from the list above, we are able to find out the granular level of repository access for each individual user as follows:

Command #2:

```
az devops user show --org {Organisation Name} --user john.doe@abc.com --query "[Username:user.name,ProjectRepoName:repo.access]"
```

The corresponding output -

```
{
  "Username": "John Doe",
  "ProjectRepoName": [
     "Develop.Env1",
     "Test.Env3",
     "UAT.Env2"
  ]
}
```

This activity gives the required data on an individual user level. However, we want the data for all the users that are provided by the user list from command one as mentioned above.

Is there a way in which we can combine both the `az devops user list` & `az devops user show` commands in a single command via a script, that would traverse all the users in the user list and for each user, using the show command provide the details of the repo access, that can then be stored as a json/table output?

Note: one approach that we can think of is- *to filter out the name/email from the list generated using command-1 and pass that list in the user section of the second command. However, the user section takes only one value at a time so not sure, how can this be achieved using CLI operations.*

Any help or suggestions on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "However, the user section takes only one value at a time" - simple to solve: `foreach($email in $listOfEmails){ az devops user show --user $email ... }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but got errors while executing the script. The actual command that gets runs within the script is `foreach($email in $listOfEmails) {az devops user show --org {Organisation Name} --user   ($email) --query "[Username:user.name,ProjectRepoName:repo.access]" >> output.json}`

ERROR: Page not found. Operation returned a 404 status code
ERROR: TF10158 The user or group name john.doe@abc.com, contains unsupported characters, is empty or too long

Comment: The issue was due to the presence of quotes **("john.doe@abc.com", "rick.stein@abc.com",..)** in the filtered output, which was being passed onto the second command of the script. 
Updated the filtered output format from JSON to Table and this successfully resolved the issue. Now getting the appropriate output in the output.json file, as per requirement.
Thanks once again for the advice on the looping logic.

Comment: That's great, consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution of this issue was by using the foreach loop logic and making use of the appropriate format for filtering the output for command one.

The snippet of the working code-

```
.......
$listOfMails = (az devops user list --org {Organisation-Name} --query members[].emailid -o table)

foreach($email in $listOfEmails)
{
    (az devops user show --org {Organisation Name} --user ($email) --query "[Username:user.name,ProjectRepoName:repo.access]")
}
...
```

This resulted in the successful extraction of data, as per requirement.